# Calling UIAlertView delegate method crashed

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview

I have a viewController class A that have a method creating a UIAlertView and implement UIAlertView Delegate method, and a NSObject model class B for processing logging and networking. In class B, just allocating an A class instance, then call the method of A. The alert view was displayed normally, but when i clicked "Ok" button, it's just crashed. I want click "Ok" button to reopen keyboard let user continue login after failured. (Had declared UIAlertView protocol in header file.)

In viewcontroller class A:

```
- (void)displayAlertViewString:(NSString *)string
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failured!"
                                                    message:string
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Ok"])
    {
        //reopen the keyboard let user continue login.
        [self.passwordField becomeFirstResponder[;
    }
```

And in model class B, i called display alert view method in the `failure block` of `AFNetworking`.

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", error);

        RDLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[RDLoginViewController alloc] init];

        [loginViewController displayAlertViewString:@"The entered email or password was incorrectly!"];
```

There is no any information in debugger, Xcode just stuck on the thread view. Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the failure block execution, your `loginViewController` is released from memory, since nobody has a strong reference to it.

When the alertView tries to access it's delegate it crashes, since its delegate is not in the memory anymore.

I'd recommend you to take a look at the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Thanks. How could i do to prevent released from memory? Why After the failure block execution, the object should be released?

Comment: It's released because there are no strong references to it. The answer here will depend on your app's architecture. Based on what you've shown, it seems reasonable that you create a strong property on the class that fires the AFNetworking request, instead of allocing and initing it on the failure block.

Comment: I add a class property in header file, than initializing class in `success block`, but still crashed, what's wrong with this?

Comment: oh no, the class object was initializing ou of `success block` and `failure block`, but they both in one method.